# Custom Publishing Statuses

Tags: content-delivery, publishing

I am writing a custom transport/deployment mechanism for SDL Tridion 2013 which pushes content to a third party application. The out of the box status labels for the publishing queue contain values like *waiting for publish*, *transporting*, *waiting for commitment* etc. Is it possible to extend this list with custom values like *waiting for import job*?

If this is possible to do in a supported way, how can it be done, and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Is tridion directly accessed by third party users OR third party users has some services to publish the content?

Comment: Neither - Tridion users publish content to a third party 'deployer-like' application which has steps for deployment which differ from  the standard Tridion Deployer. So I would like to communicate the status of these steps to the user who performed the publish action.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the "Deploying" state (which is what the tridion uses when it is processing)?

Comment: In our case deploying has about ten steps which all take time. We were hoping to display this progress to the user instead of leaving the item in "deploying" for such a long time. But if we can't change this we will have to reuse an existing status.